# How to enqueue every script in a folder automatically?

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

I have a whole entire `js` folder of scripts and it would be tedious to have to load them all with `wp_enqueue_script()` one by one.

Is there a way I can just insert the directory they are all in and it do it for me?

Comment: How many scripts are you talking about? How long? The best solution from both a convenience as well as performance perspective might very well turn out to be combining them all into one or two js files, and then enqueueing them.

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing wrong with enqueuing many files by using `wp_enqueue_script`. If you are referring to it as frustrating, then there is a simple solution for this.

PHP offers a function that can list files and directories. By using [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) you can list every `.js` file in your directory, and then enqueue them by a loop.

```
function enqueue_my_scripts(){
    foreach( glob( get_template_directory(). '/path/*.js' ) as $file ) {
        // $file contains the name and extension of the file
        wp_enqueue_script( $file, get_template_directory_uri().'/path/'.$file);
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts');
```

A side not is that `glob` uses relative path, but `wp_enqueue_script` uses URLs. That is why I used different functions to get the folder's path and URI.

Comment: Unless this is a child theme, then template should be stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

On WordPress 4.9 using the relative path (get_template_directory) returned $file as the complete path, which is unusable on a shared server. I found I had to use the substr function to return just the file name, and then build the URI from that.

```
foreach( glob( get_template_directory(). '/path/*.js' ) as $file ) {
    $filename = substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1);
   wp_enqueue_script( $filename, get_template_directory_uri().'/path/'.$filename);
}
```

Comment: I think [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) would be easier to read, and maybe even faster. :)